# I encoded a pure javascript dropdown script, it has some (toggle) problems

Tags: javascript, html

I encoded a pure javascript dropdown script, it has some (toggle) problems.

Now, when i click button dropdown opens with class tags `( .is-open .in )`.

After i am click trigger button again: it give wrong work. But i am click body or press ESC key,it closes properly..

The problem there, script remove ".is-open.in" tags, after again added... of course it's ridiculous after that.

Because for eventListener, program again run `open(e)`.

```js
const ClassName = {
  OPEN: 'is-open',
  IN: 'in',
  OUT: 'out',
  MENU: 'dropdown-menu',
}

const KeyCodes = {
  ESC: 27
}

const DefaultConfig = {
  transition: true,
}

const throwError = message => window.console.error(`bozDropdown: ${message}`);

const reflow = element => element.offsetHeight;


class bozDropdown {

  constructor(id, config) {

    this.id = id;

    this.config = Object.assign({}, DefaultConfig, config);

    this.dropdown = bozDropdown.findDropdown(this.id);

    this.menu = this.dropdown.querySelector(`.${ClassName.MENU}`);

    this.isOpen = false;
    this.isInit = false;

    this.triggers = bozDropdown.findTriggers(this.id);
    this.closeEls = null;

    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  init() {

    if (this.isInit) {
      throwError('Event listeners already added.');
      return;
    }

    this.triggers.forEach(trigger => trigger.addEventListener('click', this.open));

    this.isInit = true;
  }

  destroy() {

    if (!this.isInit) {
      throwError('Event listeners already removed.');
      return;
    }

    this.triggers.forEach(trigger => trigger.removeEventListener('click', this.open));

    this.isInit = false;
  }

  open(e) {

    if (this.isOpen) {
      return;
    }

    if (e)
      e.preventDefault();

    if (typeof this.config.beforeOpen === 'function') {

      this.config.beforeOpen();

    }

    this.menu.style.display = 'block';

    if (this.config.transition) {
      this.dropdown.classList.add(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.dropdown.classList.add(ClassName.IN);
      this.menu.classList.add(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.menu.classList.add(ClassName.IN);

      this.openWithTransition();

    } else {
      this.dropdown.classList.add(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.menu.classList.add(ClassName.OPEN);
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDismiss);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);

    this.closeEls = [...this.dropdown.querySelectorAll('[data-dismiss="dropdown"]')];
    this.closeEls.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', this.close));

    this.isOpen = true;

    if (typeof this.config.onOpen === 'function' && !this.config.transition) {
      this.config.onOpen();
    }
  }

  openWithTransition() {

    const openTransitionHandler = () => {

      this.menu.removeEventListener('animationend', openTransitionHandler);

      if (typeof this.config.onOpen === 'function') {
        this.config.onOpen();
      }
    };

    this.menu.addEventListener('animationend', openTransitionHandler);
  }

  close() {

    if (typeof this.config.beforeClose === 'function') {

      this.config.beforeClose();

    }

    if (this.config.transition) {

      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.IN);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.dropdown.classList.add(ClassName.OUT);
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.IN);
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.menu.classList.add(ClassName.OUT);
      this.closeWithTransition();

    } else {

      this.menu.style.display = 'none';
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);

      if (typeof this.config.onClose === 'function') {
        this.config.onClose();
      }
    }

    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onDismiss);
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);

    this.closeEls.forEach(button => button.removeEventListener('click', this.close));

    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  closeWithTransition() {

    const closeTransitionHandler = () => {

      this.menu.removeEventListener('animationend', closeTransitionHandler);
      this.menu.style.display = 'none';
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OUT);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OUT);

      if (typeof this.config.onClose === 'function') {
        this.config.onClose();
      }
    };

    this.menu.addEventListener('animationend', closeTransitionHandler);
  }

  onDismiss(e) {

    if (!this.menu.contains(e.target) && this.isOpen) {
      this.close();
    }

  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {

    switch (e.keyCode) {

      case KeyCodes.ESC:
        this.close();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  static findTriggers(id) {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(`[data-toggle="dropdown"][data-target="${id}"]`)];
  }

  static findDropdown(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = bozDropdown;
} else {
  window.bozDropdown = bozDropdown;
}



const dropdown1 = new bozDropdown('dropdown1', {
  onOpen: function() {
    console.log("Açıldı 1")
  },
  beforeOpen: function() {
    console.log("Açılacak 1")
  }
});
dropdown1.init();
```

```css
:root {
  --duration: 350ms;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: .5rem 0;
  margin: .125rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.dropdown.in .dropdown-menu {
  animation: scaleUp var(--duration) ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown.out .dropdown-menu {
  animation: scaleDown var(--duration) ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown1">Basic Dropdown 1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Onur</li>
      <li>Onur</li>
      <li>Onur</li>
      <li>Onur</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

For resolve this problem i am try this code: `if(this.isOpen) { return; }` **Line: 71** But it do not solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your closeTransitionHandler function is not being triggered when you click on the button element and the dropdown is already visible as the animation does not have time to end as the menu appears again when calling open() (It starts fading, but its opened again before the close animation ends, so it never really ends). This causes the out classes are never removed from the element.

A simple fix that I have tried is to set the this.isOpen = false; at the end of closeTransitionHandler function and inside the else of this.config.transition of close() function.
Code snippet below

```
  close() {
    if (typeof this.config.beforeClose === 'function') {

      this.config.beforeClose();

    }

    if (this.config.transition) {
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.IN);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.dropdown.classList.add(ClassName.OUT);
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.IN);
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.menu.classList.add(ClassName.OUT);
      this.closeWithTransition();
    } else {
      this.menu.style.display = 'none';
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OPEN);

      if (typeof this.config.onClose === 'function') {
        this.config.onClose();
      }
      this.isOpen = false;
    }

    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onDismiss);
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);

    this.closeEls.forEach(button => button.removeEventListener('click', this.close));

  }

  closeWithTransition() {

    const closeTransitionHandler = () => {

      this.menu.removeEventListener('animationend', closeTransitionHandler);
      this.menu.style.display = 'none';
      this.menu.classList.remove(ClassName.OUT);
      this.dropdown.classList.remove(ClassName.OUT);

      if (typeof this.config.onClose === 'function') {
        this.config.onClose();
      }
      this.isOpen = false;
    };

    this.menu.addEventListener('animationend', closeTransitionHandler);
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is obviously not a valid solution. But it brought a very good idea to my mind. I'll try it right now.